# How to check if two arrays of strings contain the same values (including duplicates)

Tags: node.js

I have 2 arrays which both containing strings, for example:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'a']
b = ['b', 'a', 'a']
```

I have found that I can use lodash with:

```
_.isEmpty(_.xor(a,b))
```

to make sure they both equal.
However this method seems to fail if I have duplicated values in the arrays, for example:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'a']
b = ['b', 'a']
```

the above method will return true for this case (it will print they are equal) although I have 2 'a' in a array and only 1 in b.

Any elegant ways to perform this comparison?

Comment: You could sort them and compare them one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function isEqual(a, b) {
  return [...new Set(a.concat(b)] // Get an array of unique elements of both arrays
           .filter(t =>
             // Filter on those elements whose count in both arrays is different
             a.filter(at=>at===t).length !==  b.filter(bt=>bt===t).length
            )
           .length === 0
}

console.log(['a','b'], ['b','a','a'], isEqual(['a','b'], ['b','a','a']))
console.log(['a','b','a'], ['b','a','a'], isEqual(['a','b','a'], ['b','a','a']))
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose the following if you don't want to sort the array. You take the one array and remove each item from the other. If an item cannot be removed at any time or the array remains with any items in the end, they are not equal.

```js
var a = ['a', 'b', 'a']
var b = ['b', 'a', 'a']

function areEqual(a, b) {
  var flag = true;
  b.forEach((letter) => {
    let i = a.indexOf(letter);
    if(i == -1) { flag = false; }
    else a.splice(i, 1);
  });
  if(flag && a.length == 0) { return true; }
  else { return false; }
}

console.log(areEqual(a,b));
```